# Rendering an underwater scene - with depth fall off and surface caustics

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics, ocean-simulation

I've been working on an underwater scene for a project and now reached a standstill due to an issue that I encountered. I'm trying to render a scene such as the ones in the images below, I tried using the different volume shaders available on blender but can't figure out the best combination to achieve such a look. The god ray (kinda) lights along with the depth fall off is what I aim to achieve.

best,
AJ

Pictuurres from: Pexel[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271249/how-to-make-disco-ball-reflect-lights-on-walls-using-new-shadow-caustics-from-3/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129220/how-to-create-an-underwater-scene-in-cycles/

Answer (score 1):

You could try these technics:

Create a cube that contains your scene, give it a material with the following setup: Plug a *Noise Texture*, *2D* mode, into a *ColorRamp* that you plug into the *Density* of the *Volume Scatter*, tweak a bit the rotation values of the *Mapping* node. It will fake the ray lights. Put a *Sun* above the cube. To make it more interesting you could mix the *ColorRamp* with another *Noise* (in *3D* this time):

[image]

Or create a classical *Volume Scatter* setup and put several *Spot* lights to create the rays:

[image]

To create a gradient on Z, mix your setup with a *Separate XYZ* through a *Color > MixRGB* in *Multiply* mode:

[image]

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply, I'll try to do that. Do you think adding a light path node would help get the same results?

Comment: How would you use it?